# SAS: How to maintain memory from a do loop within another do loop so that the partial output is appended together vertically using an output statement

Tags: loops, memory, sas, output

So I have this:

Initial database:

```
Variable1, variable2, value, percentvalue
Keyword1, a, 234, 0.7
Keyword1, a, 64, 0.18
Keyword1, a, 4, 0.05
Keyword1, a, 2, 0.025
Keyword1, a, 300, 0.84
Keyword2
Keyword2
Keyword3
Keyword4
Keyword4
```

and so on.

When I run this individually, it work:

```
data Filename1;
set filename0;
if variable1 = 'Keyword1' then do;
   retain sumCol;
   sumCol = sum(sumCol, percentvalue);
   if sumCol>0.95 then DELETE;
   output;
end;
```

This return the first 3 row of keyword1

Which is what I want.

But when I try to do it for the entire table which has like 600 keywords.

I'm currently running the test with only one keyword to make sure it work in the same way.

But when I run:

```
data Filename1;
set filename0;
array MyArrayVariable1{1} $ Keyword1;
do i=1 to dim(MyArrayVariable1);
  if variable1 = MyArrayVariable1[i] then do;
      retain sumCol;
      sumCol = sum(sumCol, percentvalue);
      if sumCol>0.95 then DELETE;
      output;
   end;
end;
run;
```

When I run it, It just pull an empty table instead of the selected value.

And if I get rid of the output; it pulls the entire table without filtering anything.

Comment: Why did you define an ARRAY with only one variable in it?  That means the `DO I=` loop will only execute once since the dimension of the array is only one.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce the first iteration using the array and once I get it to work, I will copy paste the name of the 500+ keywords in the database to run the loop.

Comment: Do not move the KEYWORDS from the variable into either the code or the metadata (variable names).   Leave data as data.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you just want to use BY group processing.

```
data Filename1;
  set filename0;
  by variable1 ;
  if first.variable1 then sumcol=0;
  sumCol + percentvalue;
  if sumCol<=0.95 then output;
run;
```

Note that using a SUM statement

```
sumCol + percentvalue;
```

is a simplified way to code these two statements in your original code.

```
retain sumCol;
sumCol = sum(sumCol, percentvalue);
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much. I did a few transformation to your comment and it work. I changed the : sumCol + percentvalue for : retain sumCol: sumCol = sumCol + percentvalue       And it worked. Thank you again! I would upvote this, but I don't have enough reputation to do it ^^.

Comment: The SUM statement in my code is the equivalent of the separate RETAIN and assignment statements you replaced them with.  https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lestmtsref/n1dfiqj146yi2cn1maeju9wo7ijs.htm

Answer (score 1):

BY group processing with an I/O criterion based on a groupwise computation can also be succinctly coded in what is commonly called a DOW loop in the SAS community.  One hallmark of the technique is to place the SET statement inside a DO loop.

Example:

```
data want;
  do until (last.variable1);
    SET have;
    by variable1;

    pctsum = sum(pctsum,percentvalue);
    if pctsum <= 0.95 then OUTPUT;
  end;
run;
```

NOTE:
I'm not sure of the role of your `Variable2`.  Should it be part of a hierarchy wherein the pctsum is reset if the Variable2 value changes within a Variable1 group?